# Assign row number through stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

How can i assign `Row_number` along with select through `MySQL` stored procedure, i can do it with `MS-SQL`as  described below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomersPageWise]
      @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@PageCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
                  ORDER BY [CustomerID] ASC
            )AS RowNumber
         INTO #Results
      FROM [Customers]
END
```

My Question is that ..

- How can i **initialize Parameters in `MySQL`** ( example :  `@PageIndex INT = 1`)
- in `MySQL` How to achieve

  `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
   (
       ORDER BY [CustomerID] ASC
    )AS RowNumber`

**What i had Tried**

- When i do like this

  `CREATE PROCEDURE 'dbo'.'GetCustomersPageWise'(p_PageIndex INT = 1,p_PageSize INT = 10,p_PageCount INT OUTPUT)`
  result in error as **`Incorrect syntax near =1`**
- Also i tried with

  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER;
   (
      ORDER BY 'CustomerID' ASC
   )AS RowNumber

  **result in error as** 
  Script line: 4  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `product_gid` ASC
          )AS RowNumber
     `product_gid`,
  ' at line 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomersPageWise]
      @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@PageCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET @ROW_NUMBER= 0;
      Insert INTO Results SELECT @ROW_NUMBER:= @ROW_NUMBER+ 1
      FROM Customers
END
```

Like this you can achieve your expected result.